# How iTeleport works?

Tags: iphone, ipod

can someone explain me how [this](http://www.iteleportmobile.com/) app works? I mean, is not about how to use it, is about how they transmit information from the computer to the mobile device, I just need general terms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They [run a VNC server on the computer](http://www.iteleportmobile.com/support/manual) and [set up port forwarding using UPnP](http://www.iteleportmobile.com/connect/manual).

Answer (score 0):

They're using a remote desktop protocol (VNC) to transmit the image on the screen over the internet to the client device. Individual actions (like mouse clicks) performed on the client device (e.g. an iPad) are sent over the internet back to the computer, where the RDP server emulates the action.

In order to bypass issues like NAT, they either use UPnP (automatic port forwarding) or have an intermediate server somewhere that both the client device and computer connect to.

Comment: Do you know how they connect the device and computer using the google account? Are they using a server to transmit the images or the make the connection directly?

Comment: The Google account is simply used for authentication on the VNC server. The video and other data (keypresses, mouse movement, etc) is sent directly.